# Properties of doubling metric spaces

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, geometric-measure-theory, metric-spaces

At present I work with tools that involves doubling metric space, my definition of DME is:

> A metric space $X$ is called doubling with constant $N$, where $N \geq 1$ is an integer, if, for each ball $B(x , r )$, every $\frac{r}{2}$-separated subset of $B(x , r )$ has at most $N$ points.
> A $\frac{r}{2}$-separated subset is a set of points $\{x_i\}$ such that $d(x_i,x_j) \geq \frac{r}{2}$ for $i \neq j$.

I have been studying and trying to prove some results but with the following two I haven't had much success:

1. if $X$ is a metric space such that every open ball of radius $r > 0$
   in $X$ can be covered by $M$ open balls of radius $\frac{r}{2}$ then $X$ is doubling with
   constant $M^2$.

For these I considerer a $\frac{r}{2}$ separated set in a ball $B(x,r)$
For this result try to give a set $\frac{r}{2}$ separated in the ball $B(x,r)$ and try to see its intersections with the cover that by hypothesis exists, also I had the doubt if in the statement I should have "at most M balls".

2. Let $X$ be a doubling metric space with constant $N$ and let
   $k \geq 1$ be an integer. Then every $2^{−k} r$ -separated set in every ball $B(x , r )$ in $X$ has at most $N^k$ points.

For this result I have tried to use the following characterization of the doubling metric spaces: If $X$ is a doubling metric space with constant $N$ then every
open ball of radius $r > 0$ in $X$ can be covered by $N$ open balls of radius $r/2$

but I have not been able to conclude anything in both results any hint would be much appreciated.
Also if you could recommend me books to consult the proofs of the results I would appreciate it.

Comment: Are your balls open or closed?

Comment: Are you aware of say https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubling_space and some of the references there?

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov the balls are open

Comment: @quarague yes I see these reference but I can't found these results